# how to add weightage to spacy spans?

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition, spacy-3, spacy-transformers, spancat

Let's say I'm adding specific food product separated by commas.

**Eg : The ingredients in tomato soup is tomatoes, salt, pepper. You need to heat the tomatoes till it smells like burnt apples.**

Now by previous training it can detect 4 ingredients :

1. tomato
2. salt
3. pepper
4. apple.

Apple is the wrong span detected here.

But burnt apples is not an ingredient in the dish, it is just a random reference. SO how can I stop or reduce weight-age based on phrases or way the sentence is framed?

Also, I'm using spans (spancat).
I've not used spangroup and acutally I don't know if spangroup will fix this issue.

Please let me know how I can add weightage for specific pattern or phrase in spans.

Comment: If you want your model to distinguish ingredients from non-ingredient food mentions, you'll need to provide it with more training data, particularly lots of examples of non-ingredient food mentions (like apple). However that's very difficult to learn.

Comment: Yes. exactly. Any work round?